# How to backup docker container with data and move to another server?

Tags: docker, backup

I'm definitely new to docker at all, started to use it a while ago and I need to move my stuff from one server to another. I thought that just creating a personal image will solve this issue, but nope :D.

So if I'm right, all data is saved on created volume, right? Like one of the containers is PostgreSQL.

So to move everything i need also backup the volume and export it on a new server?

https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/#backup-restore-or-migrate-data-volumes

This is what I found on their docs.

Hope somebody could help me with understanding

Comment: The Docker documentation has some commentary on [backing up and restoring named volumes](https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/#backup-restore-or-migrate-data-volumes).  Fundamentally, you need to move the data content to the other machine and re-run the same set of `docker run` commands.  All of the data should be in volumes (or bind-mounted host directories, which are a little easier to move) but where exactly depends on the specific images and your specific setup.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Docker, for default, stored images, containers, volumes, and other data, into `/var/lib/docker`, if not customized by the file `/etc/docker/daemons.json` as explained [here](https://docs.docker.com/config/daemon/#docker-daemon-directory).

In order to move all the graph to a new server you should:

- Stop docker service.
- Copy data root.
- Restart docker service.

Regards.

Comment: So I need just to copy everything from /var/lib/docker from the first server to the second, I'm right?

Comment: Yes, but after backing up the original target folder.

Comment: Sure, once i will get it, i will do that :)